# jEdit add auto Javadoc code + menu entry

Tags: java, javadoc, jedit

I need to add to the jEdit core a "Task" that is always adding Javadoc comments to all classes, methods and attributes in an x second interval. The amount of seconds is set in an popup opened from a menu entry that needs to be added as well.

I know that I need to find the main text buffer, but I don't know which one it is in the Javadoc of jEdit. And the "Task" should just be added if the "Mode" is on Java.

And how do I add a menu entry?

[JavaDoc of jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/api/index.html)

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/)

Comment: So you probably also want to check every few minutes where there is still *no* javadoc comment to add it then - maybe start [here](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/writing-plugins-part.html) - good luck!

Comment: @StefanHegny Thank you first, but I need to add it to the core code not a plugin, after more research I found the JEditBuffer class finally, where I can try to add it.

Comment: I would nevertheless recommend to try making a plugin out of it so it is easier to share and make available to others as well to disable it on instances where it is not needed at present.

Comment: Why do you think you need to add this to jEdit core instead of a plugin?

Comment: @Vampire It is a task for a certificate. It was not sure if we can create a plugin, but apparently yes. So I will do as you guys recommended, the plugin docs are better than just going to the core. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, normally you should be able to do all in plugins. :-)